# PyOpenCL Image Processing Vrs OpenCL image Processing

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

In terms of real time implementation of an Image Processing `algorithm(fitering,segmentation,matching)`, which one gives more speed : **PyOpenCL** or **OpenCL**?

1. How do I get started to use PyOpenCL?
2. What IDEs can be used to program in PyOpenCL?
3. Is there a separate SDK available for PyOpenCL or do we use the same
   OpenCL SDK given by Nvidia or AMD?

there are not much sample codes available on the net in PyOpenCL as they are in OpenCL, Please specify any link which makes everything friendly with PyOpenCL....!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyOpenCL (for Python) and OpenCL (for C/C++) are just frameworks.  You choose the framework based on the language you're using for your application.  Neither of these has Image Processing algorithms pre-built.  If you want image processing algorithms, then try libraries that are built on top of OpenCL.  I work on [ArrayFire for OpenCL](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire) that has image processing functions (available starting in 1-week) and might be useful for your efforts.  Good luck!